# When receiving multiple asynchronous fetch responses how can you choose the one that you want (ie. the one the user has requested)?

Tags: javascript, database, asynchronous, fetch

Using the example of an onChange search bar, where results are returned as the user types into the bar, if multiple fetch requests are sent to the client asynchronously with the desired response coming in before the undesired response, how can we "pick" the response that the user intended to receive while discarding the undesired response?

I know there is a specific terminology and method for doing this kind of operation but I can't seem to find it through google. Any help would be appreciated! Happy to answer questions to elaborate.

Comment: You can use observables for this, just unsubrcibe from the observables that you don't wish to show responses for(https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-search-bar-with-rxjs), or you have to maintain some kind of state to identify which is the latest request e.g. timestamps

Comment: You could send a timestamp or some other generated id in the request, and have the API return that value in its response. And then only act if the received response belongs to the request that was sent last.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can approach this problem, here are the one I can think of-

Keep track of the requests that are being made to the server in a list, and whenever you user input changes, cancel all the previous requests which are still in progress and then send the next request with the latest user input. When a request is successful, extract the data from the response.

However you might run into race condition here, so you get the response from the server before you are able cancel the request.

To solve the race condition, you can attach an identifier (e.g. timestamp, counter, the hash of user input) with each request, which will be sent back by the server with the response. You keep track of the latest request identifier and whenever you get a successful response from the server, compare its identifier with the latest identifier you have stored and discard the response if the comparison fails.